# Insert value inside dropdown list. Is it possible?

Tags: php, dropdown

I would like to ask is it possible to add value inside dropdown list using input text? Here is the code for dropdown list. How to code it?

```
  <select class="form-control" name="txt_university">
                    <option></option>
                        <option>University of Malaya</option>
                        <option>Universiti Sains Malaysia</option>
                        <option>Universiti Teknologi Malaysia</option>
                        <option>Universiti Teknologi MARA</option>
                        <option>Universiti Putra Malaysia</option>
                        <option>Universiti Kebangsaan Malaysia</option>
                        <option>Universiti Malaysia Sabah</option>
                        <option>Universiti Tenaga Nasional</option>
                        <option>Multimedia University</option>
                        </select>
```

And this is the code for user to insert another university. When user insert a university, it will store inside the dropdown list.

```
 <div class="control-group">
                      <label class="control-label">Add University</label>
                      <div class="controls">
                       <input name="txt_university" type="text" class="input-xxlarge"/> name="save">Add</button>
                      </div>
                    </div>
```

Comment: Yes this is possible.

Comment: u can do it in jquery

Comment: How does it works?? What is the code?

Comment: Yes that is possible.  **NB** You have an invalid html markup on your input field

Comment: @Anis SO isn't a free coding service. You have to show effort and have a demonstrable issue that you're having trouble resolving. As a hint, you can do this with Javascript by adding options into the DOM. JQuery will make this easier.

Comment: If Im not using DOM, will it works?

Comment: You are "using" DOM.

Comment: try my answer @Anis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need attach a function that will take value from the input field and send it to select element in form of an option, when button is clicked.

```js
var button = document.getElementById('button');

button.addEventListener('click', function() {
 

var newUniversity = document.getElementById("new_university").value;
var universityList = document.getElementById("university_list");

 universityList.options[universityList.options.length] = new Option(newUniversity, newUniversity);

});
```

```html
<select id="university_list" class="form-control" name="txt_university">
                    <option></option>
                        <option>University of Malaya</option>
                        <option>Universiti Sains Malaysia</option>
                        <option>Universiti Teknologi Malaysia</option>
                        <option>Universiti Teknologi MARA</option>
                        <option>Universiti Putra Malaysia</option>
                        <option>Universiti Kebangsaan Malaysia</option>
                        <option>Universiti Malaysia Sabah</option>
                        <option>Universiti Tenaga Nasional</option>
                        <option>Multimedia University</option>
                       </select>
                        
                        <div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label">Add University</label>
    <div class="controls">
        <input id="new_university" name="txt_university" type="text" class="input-xxlarge"/>
        <button name="save" id="button" type="button">Add</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Now it works and should solve the problem, hope you guys will upvote it if it works. JsFiddle says it's good :)

Comment: You need to wrap   javascript code with <script></script> tag before running it

Comment: I wrapped it. Is it because of something relate with my database? Its not right?

Comment: As the code works in the fiddle, you should check how to implement it to your existing file.

Comment: I'm trying. @hrvojeA

Comment: In the place of <select> .... </select> and <div>...</div> from your question, put the html from my answer/fiddle. Below it, open <script> tag and paste the javascript  code from the answer/fiddle, and close the <script> tag with </script>. E.g. (<script> var button = document......... new Option(newUniversity, newUniversity);}); </script>

Comment: Its working nowww I'm so excited! Many thanks to you for helping meeeeee! @hrvojeA  :D

Comment: Thankyou for helpinggg @MasivuyeCokile. It's working :D

Comment: Heyy, sorry. The code is working but is it temporary because when I refresh, the value is not store in the dropdown list so I need to insert back the value and repeat it when refresh :(

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible. You can append the option in select like below.

```
$('select').append($('<option>', {text:'University Name'}));
```

OR

```
$('select').append('<option>University Name</option>');
```

Please tick as answer if you satisfied with this option.

Thanks
SAMIR

Comment: where should i put that?

Answer (score 0):

Append the option with checking duplication.

```js
$('#add').click(function()
{
  if($('#new_univ').val() !="")
  {    
       var valid =true;
      $('select[name="txt_university"]>option').each(function()
      {
        //alert($(this).text());
          if($(this).text().trim()==$('#new_univ').val().trim())
          {
             valid =false;
          }
      });
      
      if(valid==true)
      {
        $('select[name="txt_university"]').append('<option>'+$('#new_univ').val()+'</option>');
  
  alert("not a duplicate and option added successfully ");

      }
      else
      {
         alert("duplicate");
      }
      
  }


});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="form-control" name="txt_university">
                    <option></option>
                        <option>University of Malaya</option>
                        <option>Universiti Sains Malaysia</option>
                        <option>Universiti Teknologi Malaysia</option>
                        <option>Universiti Teknologi MARA</option>
                        <option>Universiti Putra Malaysia</option>
                        <option>Universiti Kebangsaan Malaysia</option>
                        <option>Universiti Malaysia Sabah</option>
                        <option>Universiti Tenaga Nasional</option>
                        <option>Multimedia University</option>
                        </select>
<div class="control-group">
                      <label class="control-label">Add University</label>
                      <div class="controls">
                       <input name="txt_university" type="text" class="input-xxlarge" name="new_univ" id="new_univ" />
                       <input type="button" id="add" name="save" value="Add">
                      </div>
                    </div>
```

Comment: I've just added one university twice and the code accepted it, so the checking duplicates does absolutely nothing

Comment: try it now @MasivuyeCokile  and thanxx

Comment: You might need to adjust the code a little when u add a varsity now it alerts all the other varsities one by one